# Converting JavaFX application(.Jar) to Windows application(.exe) - Launch4j (JDK 11)

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, launch4j, javafx-11

I am trying to convert with `Launch4j`, but I have the following error:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

[image]

This is how I have the configuration:
[image]

At the moment I'm running it with a run.sh that I run with Git-bash `$ sh run.sh`

```
java --module-path "C:\Users\test\Documents\JavaFX\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar MC_Clearing.jar
```

I made this project with intellij idea and the JavaFX I used the one from gluonhq, but I can't manage to add those two missing modules to the .jar application to create the .exe.

**UPDATE**
Change Main as indicated @Slaw

```
public class Main  {
    public static class Window extends Application {
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

            GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
            int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
            int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();

            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("view.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setMaximized(true);
            stage.show();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(Window.class, args);
    }
}
```

`module-info.java`

```
module MC_Clearing {
    
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.web;
    requires javafx.swing;
    requires javafx.fxml;


    opens com.data.t140.mc_clearing;

}
```

Now I have the following error:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:222)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
        ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Thank you.

Comment: One scenario that error pops up is when JavaFX is placed on the class-path—instead of the module-path—and the main class is a subclass of `javafx.application.Application` (which causes some internal checks to see if the `javafx.graphics` module is in the _boot_ module layer). The workaround is to make a separate main class that is _not_ a subclass of `Application` and all it does is launch the JavaFX application (e.g., `Application.launch(TheAppClass.class, args)`). Though I'm not sure why JavaFX would be on the class-path given you're specifying the module-path, but I don't know Launch4j much

Comment: @Slaw I what you meant, I think that is the setting. I'm not sure

Comment: Well, some progress seems to have been made. That new error suggests the native code of JavaFX is not being found. As I said, I don't know Launch4j well, but if it is attempting to bundle the JavaFX library with your application, then it is failing to include the native libraries. In the JavaFXF SDK, those are located in the `bin` directory. Note the JavaFX JARs from Maven Central embed the native code (though that also means when using those JARs that the native code has to be extracted to someplace on the user's computer before it can be used; that happens automatically).